# How To: X11 Forwarding

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, x11, xforwarding

I am following [this article](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Displaying_CentOS_Applications_Remotely_(X11_Forwarding)) but the gedit isn't posting. I am trying to get firefox to display on a remote server to my laptop.

```
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ firefox
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: 
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: 
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
Running without a11y support!
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ gedit
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

(gedit:18861): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:31:46.554: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
```

```
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ gedit
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

(gedit:22925): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:16:21.707: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$
```

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Read `man xhost`.